# Page buttons algorithm for LazyList

Tags: android, kotlin, lazy-loading, android-jetpack-compose

I have an activity with dynamic list of Data Classes with i receive from VM.
List can be very large, so i have to show about 100 items on screen (in LazyColumn with scroll).
When i receive list i chunk it by 100 items like

```
val currentLogsList by MutableStateFlow(state.currentLogs).collectAsState()
val chunkedLogsList by MutableStateFlow(state.currentLogs.chunked(100)).collectAsState()
```

For each 100 elemnts list i nedd to create a page button so i do something like that

```
var chunkedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

LazyRow() {
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { chunkedIndex = chunkedLogsList.indexOf(it) },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),

        ) {
        Text(
            text = (chunkedLogsList.indexOf(it) + 1).toString(),
            fontSize = 14.sp
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is that i can show maximum 5 of page buttons on screen and in my case i need algorithm to dynamicaly change the index of these buttons when it clicked.
For example:
Buttons on screen is `[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]` and when user clicked on button `[4]` it changes to `[2] [3] [4] [5] [6]` and etc

**UPDATE**
Complex code fragment:

```
@Composable
fun SomeScreen() {
    val currentLogsList by MutableStateFlow(state.currentLogs).collectAsState()
    val chunkedLogsList by MutableStateFlow(state.currentLogs.chunked(100)).collectAsState()

    var chunkedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Content( currentLogsList = chunkedLogsList[chunkedIndex] )
    LazyRow() {
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = { chunkedIndex = chunkedLogsList.indexOf(it) },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),

            )  {
            Text(
                text = (chunkedLogsList.indexOf(it) + 1).toString(),
                fontSize = 14.sp
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Content(
    currentLogsList: List<LogEntity>,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(400.dp)
            .padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 20.dp, start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp),
        state = listState
    ) {
        items(currentLogsList) {
            //some magic
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You just want to centre the button for currently selected page. Is that correct? And you don't have an `items` function in the LazyRow?

Comment: @ArpitShukla updated post. I have an items in ```LazyColumn``` that takes ```List``` of elemets by index which changes by page button